# To get the value of the entries in the spinner

Tags: android

I need some help guys.

The problem is that I have a spinner that has commodities in it, such as chemicals,biscuits etc. but these commodities are stored in the database. I have written a web service that retrieves the commodities and the corresponding commodity code from database the web service works fine. I am getting the data in my android code. So I have stored the commodity in one array list say ar1, and the commodity code in one more array list say ar2. Now I want these commodity, what I have stored in ar1 to be displayed as spinner items and when user selects one of the spinner items, I must be able to retrieve the corresponding commodity code of that commodity.

Can some body help me??

I am using the below code but i am not able to get the desired result

```
String[] arr_Commodities = new String[ar2.size()];
    spinnerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ar2.size(); i++)
    {
       spinnerMap.put(ar2.get(i),ar1.get(i));
       arr_Commodities[i] = ar2.get(i);
       System.out.println(arr_Commodities[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr_Commodities);
     adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr_Commodities);
    spin_commodity.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I find nothing is wrong with this code but i am still not able to pop[ulate the spinner some one please modify the above code..thank you

Comment: you can fetch that code from second array with specific position or try to set adapter with custom object list

Comment: i am very new to android...so i can u show that with an example?it will be better for me to understand

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094457/custom-spinner-with-object-arrayadapter-cant-getresources\

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] ar1={"chemicals","biscuits"};
String[] ar2={"1","2"};

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ar1);   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);                                 
your_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

//to get the selected item position
int x=your_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Your required code is

```
String code=ar2[x];
```

Comment: String[] ar1 u have hardcoded these two values but there are lot of values that i am getting from the database so i need to populate the spinner with those no of values

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and improvise the loop on populating items:

```
final ArrayList<String[]> items = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                for(int i= 0; i <10 ; i++){//sample loop populating items
                    String[] item = new String[2];
                    item[0] = "id";
                    item[1] = "commodities";
                    items.add(item);

                }

                Spinner s = new Spinner(context);//sample spinner
                ArrayAdapter<String[]> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(context , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                s.setAdapter(adapter);
                s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String[] selected = items.get(position);
                        //commodity id
                        String comId = selected[0];
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });
```